# MasterPages Inherit another MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a website that has many MasterPages and one of them inherits from another master page and I am trying to add a control to the parent masterpage like this

```
myMasterPage.Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(theSuperStoreString.ToString()));
```

But I get the following error

```
The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases.
```

How can i do this?

Thank you

Comment: Try adding during PreInit phase?

Comment: I am sorry, I am kind of a newbie, what do you mean>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should never add any control to your parent control. It violates separation of concerns principle, breaks integrity and is the first sign of bad design (and troubles in the project).

If you have to modify Controls of your parent or another control use event, state property or interface to delegate this request to the object which is really responsible for it (parent MasterPage in that case).

Regarding to your question place a control in your parent MasterPage and show it only when someone request for it.

Comment: Please do not take any offence from my answer, it was not my point. Get rid of messing up with control collection and try to control their visibility instead should save your time here.

Comment: The problem is that they have it like this.. there is a .cs that uses a xsl to create some sort of receipt, this is a user control, then that is pass a template to a child.MasterPage, but this master page is inheriting from the parent.Master.. so I am trying to access that page from the .cs code of a user control to place a javascript tag in the body, it has to be in the body for it to work (basically its the googleAds javascript code)

Comment: Ok. If your master child.MasterPage inherit from parent.MasterPage you can add protected method to your parent.MasterPage and call it from child.masterPage. This method in turn fills in a control with a javascript passed as a parameter to this method. Does it help?

Comment: I am going to give it a shot, can it just be something like
<script>
protected void passValue(string s){//do the control thing here}; </script> something like this?

Comment: Still.. place a LiteralControl where it should be in a first place. Than in the method body just set the visibility and value.

Comment: not exactly because you cannot have a <script> tag which is 'runat' server

Comment: its weird because the main.master does not have a .cs

Comment: In the markup file please find an Inherits attribute on Master declaration, it would tell you which type is main.master derived from.

Comment: Oh no its derivating from a framework library... its getting to complicated..., I added a <asp:Literal ID="soemthing" runat="server" visible="false"> how can I now set the text to this litteral from the child MasterPage?

Comment: 1st solution. Instead of Controls.Add call Find method and provide id of that literal. Simple but ugly.
2nd. Create a new master page with a proper structure (with .cs file). Copy whole markup without master declaration to your newly created master. Replace inheritance chain to use your new masterpage. Complete the task as we talk previously.

Comment: I am kind of new to C#, can you give me a small code snipet, the last thing I would bother you with?

Comment: So Now that I found the Literal how do I pass the string to it from the child? myMasterPage.Page.Form.FindControl("googleAds");

Comment: I will do the second one with more time, lets do the first one

Comment: Cast what you found on Literal and than assign value to the Text property.

Comment: But remember I am in the UserControl, can you please show me in code how I can do this, it is probably two lines.. I am just having trouble visualizing it..

Comment: Something like this?
 Literal myliteral = new Literal();
            myliteral = (Literal)myMasterPage.Page.Form.FindControl("googleAds"); 

   and now how do i pass it to the main.master

Comment: I talk to someone here,.. we are going to go for the new master.. thank you very much for all the help.. To crazy as it is

Comment: Literal myliteral = (Literal)myMasterPage.Page.Form.FindControl("googleAds");
myLiteral.Text = theSuperStoreString.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add the control too late in the cycle, try the preinit event

added as I read your comment

here is a link to the lifecycle

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

so essentially what we are saying is you need to overrid ethe preinit event and add/create new controls there rather than the later events (where it seems you are currently trying to add)

Comment: The problem is that I need to gather some information first, how can I deal with that? (for the string I am passing)

Comment: @Superuser555 how are you passing the string, querystring, form post? either should still be available